# Port a PHP array to a MySQL schema for a ACL authorization

Tags: mysql, access-control

I'm a working with a PHP class that does ACL on my web application. It's driver based and actually it's just working with a config array. I want to migrate this array to a MySQL schema to do a driver for it. This is the actual config array:

```
$config = array(

    /**
     * Groups as id => array(name => <string>, roles => <array>)
     */
    'groups' => array(
        -1  => array('name' => 'Banned', 'roles' => array('banned')),
        0   => array('name' => 'Guests', 'roles' => array()),
        1   => array('name' => 'Users', 'roles' => array('user')),
        50  => array('name' => 'Moderators', 'roles' => array('user', 'moderator')),
        100 => array('name' => 'Administrators', 'roles' => array('user', 'moderator', 'admin')),
    ),

    /**
     * Roles as name => array(location => rights)
     */
    'roles' => array(
        '#'          => array('website' => array('read')), // default rights
        'banned'     => false,
        'user'       => array('comments' => array('create', 'read')),
        'moderator'  => array('comments' => array('update', 'delete')),
        'admin'      => array(
            'website'  => array('create', 'update', 'delete'),
            'admin'    => array('create', 'read', 'update', 'delete'),
        ),
        'super'      => true,
    ),

);
```

This is what I've been thinking:

[image: MySQL schema]

This let me associate roles to the existing groups so I've the first thing solved. What I don't know how to add is the locations and rights for each role. Obviously it will go to a separate table with a relation to a role_id but what is the best way to reproduce something like: `array('comments' => array('update', 'delete'))`?

Last thing, if a role has a boolean (like role banned or role super) it means that all true or all false. This probably fits more on roles. No?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
roles_has_access
-----
role_id FK
location_id FK
right_id FK

locations
-----
id PK
name
-- ?
-- whatever resources/locations you have here (website, admin, comments)

rights
-----
id PK
name
-- `CREATE`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `READ` etc.
```